# Counting specific character in list [python]

Tags: python

In this question, I want to ask how to count specific character in list using python:

The example of list are following below:

```
aList = [123, 'Xyz', 'zaRa', 'Abc', 123];
```

How to count "X", "R", "A" characters in that list?

The desired output is following below:

```
X = 1
R = 1
A = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map every element to a string, then stick them all together, then use the `count()` string method.

```
aList = [123, 'Xyz', 'zaRa', 'Abc', 123]
mystring = ''.join(map(str, aList))
for letter in 'XRA':
    print('{} = {}'.format(letter, mystring.count(letter)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) , something like this -

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> aList = [123, 'Xyz', 'zaRa', 'Abc', 123]
>>> astr = ''.join(map(str,aList))
>>> Counter(astr)
Counter({'3': 2, 'z': 2, 'a': 2, '2': 2, '1': 2, 'A': 1, 'X': 1, 'R': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'y': 1})
>>> c = Counter(astr)
>>> c['X']
1
>>> c['R']
1
>>> c['A']
1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
In [6]: ''.join([ item for item in aList if type(item) == str ]).count('X')
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: ''.join([ item for item in aList if type(item) == str ]).count('R')
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: ''.join([ item for item in aList if type(item) == str ]).count('A')
Out[8]: 1
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.